# I have a Netbeans project written in Java which uses commons codec. I get next error

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-commons-codec

What is the problem(package org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 does not exist.)?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're showing it in your "Test libaries" section.  Does it need to (also) be in the "Libraries" section?

Comment: happens to all of us, no worries :)